# Post Apocalyptic and disturbing Anime from my childhood

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, anime

In my childhood, like 10 years ago I watched an anime, not a series I think, it was a movie. All I can remember that it was very disturbing.

I remember some details like there was a virus or something and one city in Japan started a riot. One of the most memorable scenes was when the main character started to beat the crap out of a riot policeman, there was a lot of blood and swearing, and one girl ran to the boy to stop him.

Also in the end one man or the main character started to transform in to some big disgusting mess and got bigger and bigger and one blue serum saved him. I was trying to find that anime since then but I can't find it.

I want to see that now where I am mature enough. It is not "Vexille" like one of the most suggested

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Akira](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094625/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) *(1988)*

[image: ![enter image description here]

> A secret military project endangers Neo-Tokyo when it turns a biker
>   gang member into a rampaging psychic psychopath that only two
>   teenagers and a group of psychics can stop.

Here is a picture of the mess you describe:
[image]

And a trailer:

Comment: You are a god O.o this is it!

Comment: Gawd I haven't seen this in 25 years. It's one film that I absolutely love without ever having really understood every aspect of the story - but without getting too self analytical I wonder if it was the mystery that attracted me to it so much, again and again? Had a VHS (english dub) copy but have never seen it on any optical or digital format, or properly in Japanese..